# java dynamically choose class to execute

Tags: java, parsing, dynamic, reflection, classloader

I'm pretty sure this is something quite basic for experts, but for me, being a newbie, it gives me a hard time.

I have 3 parsers, each with it's own capabilities and in the future there will be some more parsers. Now what I want to do is this: I want my application to choose the right parser at runtime based on the page to come along.

To achieve this, I did the following: I have an Interface (IWebParser):

```
public interface IWebParser {
    public abstract Object execute(String page, URL url);
    public abstract List<SimpleWebPosting> parse(String page, URL url, List<String> tokens);

    public abstract Boolean canExecute(URL url);
}
```

Every of my parser implements this interface. I have another class called ParserControl in which there is a method submit(String page, URL url) - this is the one my program always calls, whenever there is a page to parse. This class ParserControl get's the available parser from an xml file and tries (in a while statement) if any of the parsers can parse the page in question. This is done via canExecute(URL url) method. Now, upon receiving true on canExecute, I want to execute that specific parser.

My class ParserControl looks like this:

```
public class ParserControl {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("de.comlineag.snc.parser.ParserControl");
// the list of operational web parser as taken from the properties file is stored within this structure
private static List<IWebParser> webParser; 
// the ParserControl instance - used during instantiation of the class and later to retrieve the list 
private static ParserControl pc = null;

// ParserControl is not to be directly instantiated by other classes
private ParserControl() {
    try {
        webParser = getAllParser();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException | IOException
            | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        logger.error("EXCEPTION :: error during parser execution " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
};

// Static 'instance' method - this method is called every time
// the submit method is called but can also be called implicitely to get
// an instance of ParserControl
public static ParserControl getInstance() throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    if (pc == null) {pc = new ParserControl();}
    return pc;
}


public static List<SimpleWebPosting> submit(String page, URL url, ArrayList<String> tTerms) throws XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    logger.trace("ParserControl called");
    pc = getInstance();

    while (pc.webParser.iterator().hasNext()) {
        logger.trace("trying parser " + pc.webParser.iterator().getClass().getSimpleName().toString());
        if (((IWebParser) pc.webParser.iterator().getClass().getClassLoader()).canExecute(url)) {
            return ((IWebParser) pc.webParser.iterator().getClass().getClassLoader()).parse(page, url, tTerms);
        } else {
            logger.trace("parser " + pc.webParser.iterator().getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " returned false to canExecute()" );
        }
    }

    return null;
}


// retrieves all configured parser from the properties file and creates the parser list 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> ArrayList<T> getAllParser() throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    String fileName = "webapp/WEB-INF/properties/webparser.xml";
    ArrayList<T> ar = new ArrayList<T>();

    File file = new File(fileName);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(file);

    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

    String expression = "//parser[@type='webparser']/value";
    NodeList nodeList= (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nodeList.getLength() ; i++) {
        ar.add((T) nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
        logger.trace("found parser " + nodeList.item(i).getTextContent().toString() + " in configuration file " + fileName);
    }
    return ar;
}
}
```

Now, after this lengthy introduction, my problem: When executing this, I can't instantiate the parser class, but rather get a NullPointerException. The logger.trace, within the while loop, returns this:

```
TRACE ParserControl - trying parser Itr   <--- I would expect the class name here!!!
    ERROR SimpleWebCrawler - WEBCRAWLER-Crawler Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone tell me, what I'm doing wrong here???

Comment: what line is the NPE being thrown on?

Comment: inside the while loop while (pc.webParser.iterator().hasNext()) at the if-statement: if (((IWebParser) pc.webParser.iterator().getClass().getClassLoader()).canExecute(url)) {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got some weird stuff going on here. Problems I see:

- You got some sort of singleton design pattern but are still using static variables.
- Your using an iterator wrong
- You have generics in places generics dont need to be
- Your `IWebParser` interface can return a `Boolean`, which can be null. Should it be able to return null? or should it be a primitive type (`boolean`). If it returns null and you have it in an if statement then you will get a NPE. EG: `Boolean b=null; if(b) {} // NPE!!`

Fixes:

- remove `static` from the `webParser` variable
- Get rid of generics from `getAllParser` so constructor reads `List<IWebParser> getAllParser()` (also as you can see I replaced `ArrayList` with `List`).
- Fix your iterator use, right now your getting the `ClassLoader` of the iterator and trying to cast that to a `IWebParser`, obviously wont work. Here is a working version of your loop, as you can see I declare the iterator outside and use `.next()` to get the next `IWebParser` in the loop.

```
Iterator<IWebParser> it = pc.webParser.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    IWebParser parser = it.next();
    logger.trace("trying parser " + parser.getClass().getSimpleName().toString());
    if (parser.canExecute(url)) {
        return parser.parse(page, url, tTerms);
    } else {
        logger.trace("parser " + parser.getClass().getSimpleName().toString() + " returned false to canExecute()" );
    }
}
```

Imagine an `Iterator` is an object that has a pointer at a location in a list of sorts. When you call `webParser.iterator()` it constructs a new `Iterator` that is pointing at the start of the list. Now if you were trying to loop through these and you kept calling `webParser.iterator()` you would always get an iterator that pointed at the first element. This is why its important to declare your `Iterator` outside your loop and reuse that same one inside. Its also noteworthy that you only call `.next()` on the iterator when you want to move the pointer to the next index, which is why I declare the `parser` variable and set it to the next one inside the while loop.

---

**Awnsers to comments**

*Why is this a singleton design pattern?*

A singleton is a type of object where by there should be one and only one instance ever created in the application. In Java this is generally obtained by using a `private` constructor with a public static method usually named `getInstance()`. The `getInstance()` method then will either create instance of itself if one is not yet created and stored or return the one that is stored, this is commonly done by using a static variable to store the one and only instance of the class.

When your using object oriented programming its important to take full advantage of what a class and the instance of a class means. When you incorporate static variables and methods you should always think about why they should be static. I think its safe to always go toward non static variables to start and only make it static if it needs to be. In this case the `List webParser` really belonged to the class instance and not to everyone, it was initialized in the constructor of the class, it is then used only in non static instances of the class... therefore why have it static? Also your using a singleton pattern which means there will be only 1 instance anyway!

*Error in getAllParsers()*

I assume your passing the class name of some parser to add to this `ParserControl` class. In this case you can use `Class.forName(className).newInstance()`.

Replace line `r.add((T) nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());`
with line `r.add((IWebParser)Class.forName(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent()).newInstance());`

You would need to pass the full path to the class. EG: `com.me.parsers.IFrameParser`, also FYI if you have a class inside a class you use the `$` to designate the class, EG: `com.me.parsers.ParserClass$InnerClassParser`

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. I especially like the background information given. As you probably already thought by looking at my design, I'm really just starting to learn. So please forgive me, if the following is stupid, but, why is a singleton design pattern AND static variables not good?

Comment: Oh, and I still have a problem. Now, that my getAllParsers method is List<IWebParser> getAllParser() - how do I get from the String of the parser name from my xml, to an IWebParser element??? Currently it says that the method add(IWebParser) in the type List<IWebParser> is not applicable for the arguments string

Comment: @siliconchris updated answer, also nice job on the code, some errors but that's all part of learning.